# share image from my website to instagram using Instagram Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I have requirement to share a product image and its description from my website to instagram.

Can anyone tell me is it possible?.

I went through the Instagram Graph API documentation but everything is related to Mobile Apps, can i use the same API for sharing from my desktop website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is content publishing API support for FB Instagram graph API. but that is in beta yet.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing

> The Content Publishing API is in closed beta with Facebook Marketing Partners and Instagram Partners only. We are not accepting new applicants at this time.
>
> The Content Publishing API is a subset of Instagram Graph API endpoints that allow you to publish media objects. Publishing media objects with this API is a two step process — you first create a media object container, then publish the container on your Business Account.
>
> Currently, the API can only be used to publish photos.

This would also require your Instagram account to be business account to use this API.